# Angularjs ng-model with filter let me not change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

This is my simple form:

```
 <span>{{ entry.Date | amDateFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY' }}</span>
```

By click on a "edit" button, i hide the `span´ and show the form:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entry.Date | amDateFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'" name="entry" class="input" autocomplete="off">
```

So, but if i want to change the `entry.Date` in the form, they delete my new input directly and return to his old state. If i delete the `amDateFormat` filter, it works :/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `filter` in `ng-model` or any property that any directive would want to *assign* to.

Answer (score 0):

use the `$filter` service inside the controller as below,

Ex:

```
app.controller("testCtrl" , function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.entry = {};
    $scope.entry.Date = $filter("amDateFormat")('DD.MM.YYYY');
})
```

here is the [demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dr5IrwD0oZYPwDFRkIl8?p=preview)